# Enemy timer still continuing while game is paused

Tags: python, pygame

So i'm making a platformer game in Pygame and i'm running into an issue with enemies. See, my enemies are supposed to move around on a platform, and I have a timer set up so once the timer is reacher the enemy turns around. However, I also have a pause function in my game, and the game is paused, while the enemies don't move, the timer for the enemies to turn around is still going. Then what happens is that the enemy will turn around when its not supposed to, and then it will appear that the enemy is in the air. What I want to happen is the timer to pause while the game is paused. Here is my code:
Enemy Code:

```
class enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,x,y,end,speed):
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pg.image.load("enemy.png")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
    self.alive = True
    self.health = 3
    self.end = end
    self.speed = speed
    self.timer = pg.time.get_ticks()

def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.timer >= self.end:
           self.timer = now
           self.speed *= -1
        if self.health == 0:
            self.kill()
```

Here is the Pause code:

```
def pause_screen(self):
    self.paused = True

    while self.paused:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()

            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_p:
                    self.paused = False

                elif event.key == pg.K_q:
                    pg.quit()

        self.screen.fill(WHITE)
        self.draw_text(str('PAUSED'),70,BLACK,400,200)
        self.draw_text(str('Press p to unpause'),50,BLACK,400,300)
        self.draw_text(str('Press q to quit game'),50,BLACK,400,400)
        pg.display.flip()
        self.clock.tick(5)
```

Heres how I spawn my enemies:

```
    for ene in self.enemy_list:
        e = enemy(*ene)
        self.all_enemy.add(e)
        self.all_sprites.add(e)
```

Heres my run class if you need it

```
        self.playing = True
    while self.playing:
        self.clock.tick(FPS)
        self.events()
        self.update()
        self.draw()
        self.load_level()
```

Also the enemy class isn't in the main game loop like the pause class is.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted code is not a stand-alone example.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get the time that the pause menu is open for and take that off the timer.

You will need 2 variables

```
pauseTime = 0
pauseStart = 0
```

you can then take off `pauseTime` from the timer so

```
if now - self.timer - pauseTime >= self.end:
```

Now to get how long the pause menu is open for

```
def pause_screen(self):
    self.paused = True
    pauseStart = pg.time.get_ticks()

    while self.paused:
        ...
    pauseTime += pg.time.get_ticks() - pauseStart # add the time so it doesnt reset after the second pause menu
    pauseStart = 0
```

Because your pause screen has its own while loop, the timer shouldn't get calculated. but if it still does, what you can do is only calculate it if not in the pause menu so

```
if pauseStart == 0:
    if now - self.timer - pauseTime >= self.end:
```

---

```py
    now = pg.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.timer - self.pauseTime >= self.end:
         self.timer = now
         self.speed *= -1
         self.pauseTime = 0
```

```py
    def pause_screen(self):
        self.paused = True
        self.pauseStart = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        while self.paused:
            for event in pg.event.get():
                if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                    pg.quit()

                if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pg.K_p:
                        self.paused = False

                    elif event.key == pg.K_q:
                        pg.quit()

            self.screen.fill(WHITE)
            self.draw_text(str('PAUSED'),70,BLACK,400,200)
            self.draw_text(str('Press p to unpause'),50,BLACK,400,300)
            self.draw_text(str('Press q to quit game'),50,BLACK,400,400)
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(5)
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()  
        for enemy in self.all_enemy:
            enemy.pauseTime += now - self.pauseStart
        self.pauseStart = 0
```

Comment: Ok, so I did that, and what happens is after i unpause, the enemy now is able to turn around when its supposed to, but then when it goes the other way, it goes farther that its supposed to, and then it comes back around it still turns around when its supposed to.
For example, if an enemy is going right, and i pause and unpause, the enemy will still turn left properly, but then it goes left for too far, and when it turns right it goes all the way back to when it turns left again properly. Sorry if this is kinda hard to understand.

Comment: @ArjunSharma Right, so it seems like when you change direction, the timer gets reset but not the `pauseTime`, so if you think about it, when it goes left, it will start at -3 seconds if you paused for 3 seconds, so when you change direction, make `pauseTime = 0`

Comment: Alright, so once I do that, the same problem from the beginning come. Its fine if you can't solve this one, it seems really hard to solve, and I don't think removing a pause screen will be the biggest issue for my school.

Comment: @ArjunSharma So i got all your code from last time and did this and it worked fine, the player did start moving slightly off the platform but after pausing multiple times, it followed same path. i added the code i made in the answer in case you made a silly mistake. otherwise you can chnage the movement from time to distance so it moves until it reaches a point instead of for a certain amount of time